# Como montar uma matriz no R sendo os valores a subtração de valores de um vetor

Tags: r, matriz

Como fazer para criar uma matriz no R, cujos valores sejam o resultado de uma subtração de valores de um vetor?
ex.:

Vetor

```
x <- c(a, b, c)
```

Matriz

```
1 a-a  a-b  a-c
2 b-a  b-b  b-c
3 c-a  b-b  c-c
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A função `outer` foi feita para responder ao problema da pergunta. Por defeito assume a função `"*"` para calcular o produto externo (Wikipedia em [Português](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Produto_di%C3%A1dico), em [Inglês](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Outer_product)), mas pode-se passar qualquer outra função.

```
a <- 1
b <- 3
c <- 6
x <- c(a, b, c)

outer(x, x, '-')
#     [,1] [,2] [,3]
#[1,]    0   -2   -5
#[2,]    2    0   -3
#[3,]    5    3    0
```

Answer (score 1):

Só pensar na matriz como um conjunto de vetores, aí vocÊ forma as linhas e colunas e junta numa matriz.
Aqui já feito de uma vez, crio um vetor com as linhas concatenadas e depois transformo em uma matriz com 3 linhas.

```
x <- c(1,2,3)

m <- matrix(c(x[1]-x, x[2]-x, x[3] - x), nrow =  3, byrow = T)
```